# Updating model in Laravel 4 cause a function, with the model as input, to get called twice

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a frustrating bug that I am not sure is related to Laravel but maybe PHP instead.

A little context: I am building a somewhat complex task system for handling the workflow process of a support ticket (at least my system can be roughly translated to such a system).

I am using the following piece of code if a ticket has exceeded it's deadline at it's current workflow step. A workflow step can have a deadline associated.

```
public static function proceedToFallbackStep($submission_id)
{
    $submission = Submission::find($submission_id);
    $currentworkflowstep = $submission->currentworkflowstep;
    if ($currentworkflowstep != null)
    {
        $fallbackstep = $currentworkflowstep->fallbackto;
        if ($fallbackstep != null)
        {
            WorkflowController::performWorkflowStepAction($fallbackstep->id,$submission_id);

            $submission->currentworkflowstep()->associate($fallbackstep);
            $submission->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that the WorkflowController::performWorkflowStepAction method for some reason is getting called twice. The method is among other things sending emails and updating a table. Let me give my thoughts with the proceedToFallbackStep method. First of all it is checking if the ticket's (in the code referred to as a submission) has a current workflow step associated, which in some situations might not be the case. Then it is checking if the current workflow step has a fallback step associated. If so it executes the action related to the fallback step. Now this works as intended, but when I, after running the WorkflowController::performWorkflowStepAction, update the ticket's current workflow step association the WorkflowController::performWorkflowStepAction is executed again and I have no idea why. If I leave out the

```
$submission->currentworkflowstep()->associate($fallbackstep); //This is the line causing the bug
$submission->save();
```

lines it works as it should, but then the ticket has a wrong current workflow step associated. I have tried updating the ticket's current workflow step association using DB::raw, but the result is the same. Any ideas what the problem might be?